# Need wordpress environment code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a problem. This code is well in php. I am trying make that WordPress environment code. What is problem on my code? I cant understand.
Thanks

**PHP Code:**

```
$final_array = array(); 
$sql="select hotel FROM hotels"; 
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    foreach($api_array as &$value){ 
        if($myrow['hotel'] == $value['property_name']){ 
            $final_array[] = $value; 
        } 
    } 
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

**WordPress:**

```
foreach($array as $api_array){

        $final_array = array(); 
        $sql = $wpdb->get_results( "select hotel FROM hotels" );
        //$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        while ($myrow = $sql(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            foreach($api_array as &$value){ 
                if($myrow['hotel'] == $value['property_name']){ 
                    $final_array[] = $value; 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach($array as $api_array){

    $final_array = array(); 
    $Results = $wpdb->get_results( "select hotel FROM hotels",ARRAY_A );
    $RowCount  =  $wpdb->num_rows;

    if($RowCount>0){
         foreach($Results as $Result){ 
            foreach($api_array as &$value){ 
            if($Result['hotel'] == $value['property_name']){ 
                $final_array[] = $value; 
            } 
            } 
          }
     }

}
```